# Presto CLI command in a for loop

Tags: python, command-line, presto

I am new to shell scripting I am getting error for below code. My aim is to use a presto query in a loop, so that I can execute that query multiple times from python.

To simplify please view the below code.

```
import os
for month in [2, 3]: 
    cmd = f"presto --execute 'Select * from table where year=2020 and month = {month}' --output-format CSV_HEADER >> some_directory/test.csv"
    result = os.system(cmd)
    print(f"query ran with exit code {result}")
```

This outputs

```
query ran with exit code 256
query ran with exit code 256
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your query is failing, check the logs to see why

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, piping output (`>>`) doesn't work when executed from a script like this. Because that's a terminal/shell functionality, instead you need to capture the `result` and write it to a file manually. Otherwise your system will try to execute your full command line including `>> some_directory/test.csv` as an executable.